# How to relate 1 table conditionally with 2 other tables

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, backend, typeorm

I have 1 entity called **USERS**, and then i have two others **PASSENGERS** and **DRIVERS**. When im creating a user depending of its **rol** (it can be passenger or driver) i need to introduce conditionally in the passenger table o driver table. I dont know how to make that conditional relation.
I also tried to create a driver/user and then put it into the USERS table, but i neither know how to "accept" in users table one or other entity (Because never a driver will be a passenger, and viceversa)

At the moment im creating the user and depending of its rol i introduce that data in the driver entity or passenger entity. But they have differents ID, how can i relate them?

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBUeJ.png)
[drivers table (they have different id)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOqHs.png)

```
    @Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column('text')
    fullName: string;

    @Column('text', {
        unique: true
    })
    email: string;

    @Column('text', {
        unique: true
    })
    phoneNumber: string;

    @Column('text')
    gender: string;

    @Column('float', {default: 0})
    calification: number

    @Column('text')
    id_provincia: string;

    @Column('text')
    id_localidad: string;

    @Column('text')
    bornDate: string;

    @Column('text')
    createdAt: string;

    @Column('text')
    rol: string;

    @Column('boolean', {
        default: false
    })
    blocked: boolean;
```

when i add a new user in my service i do this:

```
    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    try {
      const user = this.userRepository.create(createUserDto)
      user.createdAt = new Date().toISOString()
      await this.userRepository.save(user)
      if (user.rol === 'client') {
        await this.clientService.create(createUserDto)
      } else if (user.rol === 'driver') {
        await this.driverService.create(createUserDto)
      } else {
        await this.adminService.create(createUserDto)
      }
      return user
    } catch (error) {
      this.handleDBExceptions(error)
    }
  }
```

Im working with nestJS and postgreSQL+typeORM

Comment: What @TheImpaler suggested and use UNION

Comment: Yeah when i create a users i add that info to the other table depending on its rol, but how can i use the USER_ID in the other table?

Comment: @BarryCarter This question sounds like it's about entity inheritance. If that's the case there are 6 ways of implementing a physical model for it; I can't really understand which one the OP is using, so I removed my initial comment.

Comment: Are you asking a design question or a question about an `INSERT` or `SELECT` statement? If you have code statement, update the question to include that code please.

Comment: Also, if this is a design question, please update the question with the table definitions. The code for it, not an image. It's hard to tell how the relationship is defined with the current information.